# How to leverage browser cache in node.js?

Tags: node.js, browser-cache

My website is running on node.js server and when i inspect my website on google page insight tool, it shows me to leverage browser cache. 
I have been searching a lot for this on internet but no luck yet.
If anybody has any idea how leverage browser cache in node.js please let me know.

Answer (score 8):

Browser cache is mostly controlled by the user, outside of Node's control. The only thing you can really do is to set max-age header on static files served by Node.js.

Assuming you're using express, to cache a file for one day:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: 86400000 }));
```

Comment: I already did that but i want to implement '304 not modified' status and 'if- modified-since' headers so that i don't have to request the server for the files which are not been modified.

Comment: I have done this but google page inspect still says to Leverage browser caching (H)